# Assigning value to a model property on bootstrap button click in mvc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a bootstrap button in Index.cshtml file as below:

```
<button type="button" id ="btnSelect" class="btn btn-default">
      Thai Restaurant
</button>
```

And I have a property defined in my model class as below:

```
    public string RestaurantID { get; set; }
```

Now, I want, after I click, 'Thai Restaurant' button, RestaurantID property is assigned a value as say '1'.
I want to assign the value to RestaurantID property in my Index.cshtml file itself.

I tried using below approach.

Added

```
@Html.HiddenFor(e=>e.RestaurantID)
```

And then added JavaScript code:

```
<script>
     $('#btnSelect).click(function()
      {
         document.getElementById("RestaurantID").value = '1';
      })
</script>
```

I also tried using `on.(click, function()...)` but even that didn't help

Is there any way to do that - Assigning value to a model property on bootstrap button click?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you get when you post the form? Was RestaurantIDnot filled in the post request received at the action ? I recommend to you normal HTML hidden element like `<input type='hidden' />` as helper  hidden will preserve the last served state

Comment: When I click the button, nothing happens.. value does not get assigned. My javascript code does not get hit on button click.

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed to close the quote ' in **$('#btnSelect')**
2. remove the `type="button"` from the button tag

```js
$('#btnSelect').click(function(){
        alert()
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="btnSelect" class="btn btn-default">
      Thai Restaurant
</button>
```

Comment: removing `type='button'` will cause a postback.

Comment: @KhairulIslam : If you can see my Comment, I specifically asked for it. And as per the reply from OP, it is eveident to expect a postback ;)

Comment: @KhairulIslam :What do you think now ?

Comment: if a postback is made then the script will not execute. then how the value of the hidden field will get set? and as per OP's question the button is not looks like a submit button.

Comment: Hah And why do you think the postback will happen before the allocation of the value... It can be handled... there is no race condition ;)

Comment: looks like you'r okay, then make some edit though i can't remove the downvote now, i will remove my downvote after then.